# A call stack simulation for recursive binary tree traversal algorithms

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, simulation

Does anyone have a link to a good call stack simulation for recursive binary tree traversal algorithms. I have [this](http://www.qmatica.com/DataStructures/Trees/AVL/AVLTree.html) so far but the call stack simulation is not included. I would appreciate something similar to [this](http://www.animatedrecursion.com/simple/fact.html) **Please note: The latter link requires you to run a java applet which might be a security risk since client-side java is still vulnerable**

I have tried stepping through the code in Netbeans but a step by step visual presentation would aid to greater understanding.

Answer (score 0):

One of that is [BTree simulation](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/mukundan/dsal/BTree.html).

Comment: I came across that one too when I did a google earlier but it wasn't compelling because it lacked the call stack simulation. I hope isn't a wild goose chase